# How can I add a custom Angular component as a block in GrapesJS editor?

Tags: angular, grapesjs

I'm trying to add a custom Angular component as a block in the GrapesJS editor, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work. I've followed the instructions in the GrapesJS documentation and created a plugin that registers the component type, but when I try to add the block to the editor, it doesn't appear.

Can anyone help me figure out how to add a custom Angular component as a block in GrapesJS editor? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!